# Prepare state in between benchmark iterations

Tags: rust

I'm building benchmarks using the `#[bench]` attribute from the test crate. I'm trying to benchmark a method that takes a mutable slice of integers as input. The value of these integers determine how fast the method runs i.e. slice full of 1s runs faster that slice full of 9s. Each time the benchmark runs the values in the array are transformed and increase in value. To prevent this I want to prepare the input array, with the same values, before each benchmark iteration and not just once at the beginning. The methods on `Bencher` didn't seem to offer the ability to achieve this but thought I may be missing something.

Is there a way to achieve something like the following?

```rust
#[bench]
fn crunch_numbers(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut input = gen_input();

    // This `b.prepare()` method doesn't exist. Using it to 
    // illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.
    b.prepare(|| {
        // Things in here don't contribute to the benchmark results
        input = gen_input();
    })

    b.iter(|| {
        // I don't want to add `input = gen_input();` in here
        // because I don't want the input preparation to pollute
        // the benchmark results of `method_im_benchmarking`.
        method_im_benchmarking(&mut input);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think built in bench has something like that. AFAIK it only answer the needs of std. You can use a crate like `criterion`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing there's anything builtin, but you can do this yourself:

```
#[bench]
fn crunch_numbers(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let raw_input = gen_input();
    let mut input = raw_input.clone()

    b.iter(|| {
        input.copy_from_slice (raw_input[..]);
        method_im_benchmarking(&mut input);
    });
}
```

Comment: Won't that affect the benchmarking? I think the question is about how to make it so that it's not counted in the total time.

Comment: @BlackBeans most benchmark frameworks run the code multiple times for each measurement. There is no way for them to get the time of a single iteration, so there is no way to take the init completely out of the picture. This is a single copy, which should have minimal impact on the timing.

Comment: @BlackBeans Only the thing inside `iter()` is measured. But the copy... it may have a noticeable overhead depending what you're benchmarking.